# sql finding total of hours worked

Tags: sql

i have 2 tables worker and crew i need to find out the total number of hours ever worked by those worker that work in the particular crew on a particular date

my worker table have the following column 
worker(workerno, name)

and my crew table have the following column
crew(crewno, workerno, date, noofhours)

so my question is how do i find the total number of hours worked ever for the crew(a crew can have a lot of workers) of a particular date

Comment: By which column in table `crew` do you identify the crew?

Comment: crewno will identify the crew

Answer (score 0):

`Select c.hours from worker as w inner left join crew as c on c.workerno = w.workerno where c.date=..`